# How to get the listitems async from a SharePoint 2010 webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, asynchronous, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a Web api in C#. In the Webapi I make a call to a SharePoint webservice.

In the method i use the method listservice.GetListItems. The problem is that it isn't async and i would like to have it async. Is there a possiblity to make it async?

```
 //create listservice instance
            var listService = GetListService();
            //Get the listName and rowlimit
            string rowLimit = MaxItemsList;

            //Create elements for the faq list
            XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
            var sPList = listService.GetList(listName);
            if (sPList != null)
            {
                //get the faq items
                return listService.GetListItems(listName, string.Empty,   query, viewFields, rowLimit,
                    queryOptions, null);
            }
```

I hope you guys can help me me

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [SharePoint Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx) methods could be invoked *asynchronously*, the following example demonstrates how to convert your example:

```
using (var listService = GetListService(webUri,userName,password))
{
     listService.GetListAsync(listName, listName);
     listService.GetListCompleted += ProcessListResult;
}
```

where

```
    static void ProcessListResult(object sender, GetListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = sender as Contoso.Lists;
        var listName = e.UserState as string;

        var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        var ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
        var ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
        var ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
        proxy.GetListItemsAsync(listName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
        proxy.GetListItemsCompleted += ProcessListItemsResult;
    }

    static void ProcessListItemsResult(object sender, GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //omitted for clarity...
    }
```